# Can I get a .patch file from a svn commit without svn?

Tags: svn, url, patch

I was wondering if it's possible to extract a diff or patch file from a svn commit, directly from the url without needing svn?

For example, if I'm given the following GitHub url of a specific commit, there is a trick where I can just add .diff to the url and get the diff file:

[GitHub Commit page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/2fc5c01c7d4ba31b266ae656fd41b133f751ae16) ->
[GitHub Diff from that Commit page](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commit/2fc5c01c7d4ba31b266ae656fd41b133f751ae16.diff)

On sourceforge, I have to download the entire trunk then generate my patch as follows:

`svn checkout svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/saga-gis/code-0/trunk saga-gis-trunk`

`svn diff -r r1918:r1919 > saga-2.1.0-vigra-bug173.patch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a diff with a web browser but with a svn client you can get a diff without a checkout.

The following command will give you the diff without the checkout:

```
svn diff -c 1919 svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/saga-gis/code-0/trunk > saga-2.1.0-vigra-bug173.patch
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to still encourage other answers if someone knows of a way or if it's made available in the future.

Comment: Just for clarity, some sites might be running viewvc or various web apps that are designed to allow this sort of interaction.  But that's not a core feature of Subversion.  For instance sourceforge has something like this, to use your own example: http://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/code-0/1919/  GitHub is very much like a sourceforge in this respect, they have a webapp on top of Git.  Git doesn't provide anything like the feature you want natively, and actually you would have to download the repo to get a diff.

Comment: I can get a diff from any github commit by modifying the url. This allows them to be retrieved, without requiring a git client, to a file with wget or something. Sourceforge only lets me view the diff, not actually retrieve it (can always copy and paste). I will need svn to get any patch from svn commits on sourceforge. So I guess it would be nice to be able to get patches from svn commits via sourceforge hosted projects at the website.